# ERROR ITMS-9000:"Missing required icon file. The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPhone / iPod Touch of exactly '120x120' pixels

Tags: ios, xcode, upload, icons, app-store

ERROR ITMS-9000:"Missing required icon file.  The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPhone / iPod Touch of exactly '120x120' pixels in .png format for IOS versions >= 7.0."

I am getting this error when trying to upload my app to the app store.  I have loaded all my icons using the image asset catalog (and even tried loading icon files without the catalog).

Also, not sure why xcode wants me to upload iPhone app icons when this is an iPad app?

Anyone have any ideas?  complete stuck on this one

thanks

Comment: Easy solution is just add an icon of 120x120, right? As to why they require it for an iPad only app I don't know, but seems like the solution is pretty obvious, no?

Comment: thanks Mike.  I think I needed to recreate the archive and then validate the app after making the change to the app icon.  Posted it below.  thanks for responding

Answer (score 1):

turns out I just rebuilt the application and created a new archive.

I think creating a NEW archive was the trick. So needed to delete the old one and create the new archive which included the correctly size app icons.

If you just correct the app icons and try to validate an the existing archive it will produce the same error.

Hope this helps anyone else who encounters this issue

Comment: Solved it for me!

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1 :** 
**Choose Images.xcassets**
[image: Choose Images.xcassets]

**Step 2 : Resize Icons in below pixels then drag and drop to corresponding position.**

[image]